# shell scripts to increment time in --rfc-3339 format

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, fedora

I want to increment time in -rfc-3339 format and have used following command :

```
`date --date="(date --rfc-3339=seconds) + 5 minutes"`
```

but after increment current time by 5 minutes, it shows the incremented system time in standard format :

`Thu Feb  2 20:06:30 IST 2017`.

I want the desired output in `--rfc-3339` format i.e

`2017-02-02 20:06:30+05:30`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you look at  your system's `man date`? There may be an exact option, else you'll have to build it up from the parts, i.e. `+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S...`? Good luck.

Comment: hello shellter, I have looked into man page but haven't found exact parameter to retain the incremented date in the mentioned format.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, finally found solution by myself "date -d "15 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple. The `--rfc-3339` flag tells the `date` command how to format its output, but you're putting it *inside* the specifier for the *input* date — what date to format.

In your command

```
date --date="(date --rfc-3339=seconds) + 5 minutes"
```

the `--date="stuff"` part tells the command which date you want to show (as opposed to the default of "right now"). It *looks* like you might be doing some sort of math with "take the current date and add five minutes", but actually the part in `()` is not valid input and is ignored. You could say `date --date="(colorless green ideas sleep furiously) + 5 minutes"`, and you'll get the same results — or just `date --date="+5 minutes"`.

But of course, that's in the standard output format. To get it in RFC 3339 format, simply add that flag, *outside* of the input date string:

```
date --date="+5 minutes" --rfc-3339=seconds
```

and there you go.

Comment: Note that unsigned numbers are taken as positive numbers in date input formats, so you _could_ just do `--date="5 minutes"`, but I find it more readable to always include the sign so the addition is obvious.